# Problems with multi-page \lstlistings and \footnotes with the liuthesis document class

Tags: listings, color, footnotes

Using the liuthesis document class described at http://www.control.isy.liu.se/student/exjobb/liuthesis/liuthesis.html (download link: http://www.control.isy.liu.se/student/exjobb/liuthesis/liuthesis.zip) the line separating the footnote from the main text picks up the background color of the lstlisting (which crosses a page boundary) in the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ida]{liuthesis}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{CodeBGColor}{gray}{0.92}
\lstset{
 basicstyle=\Huge,
 backgroundcolor=\color{CodeBGColor}
}

\begin{document}

\footnote{Lorem ipsum...}
\begin{lstlisting}
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? Is this a bug in the liuthesis document class?

`\listfiles` output:

```
 *File List*
liuthesis.cls   2007/01/13 liuthesis Class v. 1.3 
lmodern.sty     2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
fontenc.sty
t1enc.def       2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
latin1.def      2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file  
babel.sty       2008/07/06 v3.8l The Babel package
swedish.ldf     2005/03/31 v2.3d Swedish support from the babel system
english.ldf     2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
ida.ltd
book.cls        2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
bk12.clo        2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)  
keyval.sty      1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty        1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
pdftex.def      2009/08/25 v0.04m Graphics/color for pdfTeX
geometry.sty    2008/12/21 v4.2 Page Geometry
ifpdf.sty       2009/04/10 v2.0 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)  
ifvtex.sty      2008/11/04 v1.4 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
crop.sty        2003/05/20 v1.9 crop marks (mf)
color.sty       2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)   
color.cfg       2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive 
amsmath.sty     2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
amstext.sty     2000/06/29 v2.01
amsgen.sty      1999/11/30 v2.0
amsbsy.sty      1999/11/29 v1.2d
amsopn.sty      1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
amssymb.sty     2009/06/22 v3.00
theorem.sty     1995/11/23 v2.2c Theorem extension package (FMi)
thp.sty         1995/11/23 v2.2c Theorem extension package (FMi)
listings.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
lstmisc.sty     2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
t1lmr.fd        2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
ot1lmr.fd       2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
omllmm.fd       2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
omslmsy.fd      2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
omxlmex.fd      2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
umsa.fd         2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
umsb.fd         2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols B
***********
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: After some experimentation I realized this only happens with the liuthesis document class I'm using. I guess this suddenly became a very small-audience type of question :/

Comment: I cannot reproduce this bug, using this example: http://pastebin.com/HaA63dPJ (Edit: OK, I see that you are using another class)

Answer (score 1):

The code in `liuthesis.cls` below causes the problem:

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vspace*{-3\p@}
  \noindent\rule{.5\textwidth}{.5\p@}\vspace*{2.6\p@}
}
```

(The original definition is `\kern -3\p@ \hrule \@width .4\columnwidth \kern 2.6\p@`.)

You can just delete it in the class, or use this:

```
\let\savefootnoterule\footnoterule
\documentclass[12pt,ida]{liuthesis}
\let\footnoterule\savefootnoterule
```

---

Actually, it may be a bug of `listings` (or output route of LaTeX?). The old definition of `\footnoterule` has no extra height/depth, thus it looks fine and hide the problem. But I've nothing to do with it.